# How do you configure Netplan on Ubuntu to store 802.1x credentials securely?

Tags: networking, password, authentication, netplan

In an 802.1x enterprise network, I can use NetworkManager to configure 802.1x parameters, including the password. This all works, but requires storing the password in cleartext.

We are trying to use Netplan to store the credentials more securely (as a hashed password), but we cannot make the 802.1x connections authenticate.

I haven't been able to find a good guide for building a Netplan configuration that includes 802.1x credentials.

(UPDATE: There is a bug in Netplan about hashed password, https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/pull/78), which seems to be the main issue)

---

Here is a file that does not work

```
network: 
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: 
    enp0s31f6:
      auth:
        key-management: 802.1x
        password: hash:some-stuff-here
        method: peap
        identity: ghewett
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4
      gateway4: 5.6.7.8
      nameservers:
        search: [cisco.com, otherdomain]
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2.2.2.2
```

(IP's and credentials changed )

This gives us

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:19354): DEBUG: 09:23:41.614: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:19354): DEBUG: 09:23:41.614: starting new processing pass
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 7 column 6: unknown key auth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://netplan.io/examples, and the https://netplan.io site in general has good info. Make sure to `sudo netplan --debug generate` to check .yaml files, and generate config files, and then `sudo netplan apply` to make them active.

---

```
Authentication

Netplan supports advanced authentication settings for ethernet and wifi interfaces, as well as individual wifi networks, by means of the auth block.

auth (mapping)

    Specifies authentication settings for a device of type ethernets:, or an access-points: entry on a wifis: device.

    The auth block supports the following properties:

    key-management (scalar)
        The supported key management modes are none (no key management); psk (WPA with pre-shared key, common for home wifi); eap (WPA with EAP, common for enterprise wifi); and 802.1x (used primarily for wired Ethernet connections).
    password (scalar)
        The password string for EAP, or the pre-shared key for WPA-PSK.

    The following properties can be used if key-management is eap or 802.1x:

    method (scalar)
        The EAP method to use. The supported EAP methods are tls (TLS), peap (Protected EAP), and ttls (Tunneled TLS).
    identity (scalar)
        The identity to use for EAP.
    anonymous-identity (scalar)
        The identity to pass over the unencrypted channel if the chosen EAP method supports passing a different tunnelled identity.
    ca-certificate (scalar)
        Path to a file with one or more trusted certificate authority (CA) certificates.
    client-certificate (scalar)
        Path to a file containing the certificate to be used by the client during authentication.
    client-key (scalar)
        Path to a file containing the private key corresponding to client-certificate.
    client-key-password (scalar)
        Password to use to decrypt the private key specified in client-key if it is encrypted.
```

Source: https://netplan.io/reference#authentication

**Update #1:**

Note: make sure there are no TABS in your .yaml file...

Add your certs, restore the IP's, and try this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      auth:
        key-management: 802.1x
        method: peap
        identity: "ghewett@example.com"
        ca-certificate: my_ca.pem
        client-certificate: my_cert.pem
        client-key: my_key.pem
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4
      gateway4: 5.6.7.8
      nameservers:
        search: [cisco.com, otherdomain]
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a sample working configuration for wired on 18.04? Our attempts at building one have failed and we're not sure if we have a bug or a configuration error.

Comment: It was only marginally helpful; I already read everything on the netplan.io site and was looking for field tested examples, not a pointer to the documentation.

Comment: @PhillipRemaker edit your question to include the .yaml file that you're running with and we'll take a look. No promises, but we'll take a look for you. Each .yaml is custom to every site, so you may not get a plug 'n play answer.

Comment: Here is a file that does not work 
```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      auth:
        key-management: 802.1x
        password: hash:some-stuff-here
        method: peap
        identity: fluffy
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4
      gateway4: 5.6.7.8
      nameservers:
        search: [cisco.com, otherdomain]
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2.2.2.2

```
(IP's and credentials changed )

Comment: That above files gets the following error

This gives us 
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:19354): DEBUG: 09:23:41.614: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:19354): DEBUG: 09:23:41.614: starting new processing pass
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 7 column 6: unknown key auth

Comment: Sorry for formatting of file in comment above - you can find the file at in a formatted version at https://gist.github.com/fluffy/ff23a868071781c90e5cd6a99ff2736f

Comment: @CullenFluffyJennings See Update #1 in my answer. Are you taking over for Phillip? Report back.

Comment: @PhillipRemaker See Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: I had originally asked on behalf of @cullenfluffyjennings.

Comment: @heynnema - Thanks - I will try and out and let you know how it goes. Due to a couple other things going on it will take me a bit of time to get back to this but very much appreciate your help.

Comment: The version of netplan.io in Ubuntu 18.04 as of March 13, 2019 is so old that it does not support the auth configuration for wired networks. If you download the latest netplan from https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan and compile it, then it will work for some limited configurations with a config file does not hash the password. However there is a bug if the password is hashed which causes it not to work The version of netplan.io in Ubuntu 18.04 as of March 13, 2019 is so old that it does not support the auth configuration for wired networks.

Comment: If you download the latest netplan from https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan and compile it, then it will work for some limited configurations with a config file does not hash the password. However there is a bug if the password is hashed which causes it not to work which is sad given no one should save unencrypted password on disk. I'm working on a PR to fix that bug - when that is fixed then then the config file at https://gist.github.com/fluffy/e2a202a0816299d519dabf7bbed2f7bb does generate a WPA that correctly authenticates and works for me.

Comment: I'm still working on making happen automatically on book but I suspect I just broke something while trying things on the machine so I will report back on that later.

Comment: Netplan bug reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1819831

Comment: PR to fix bug at https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/pull/78

Comment: @CullenFluffyJennings since my script doesn't use hashed passwords, but rather certs, won't it work?

Comment: @heynnema It would not work on default Ubuntu 18.04 as it does not support any of this stuff but with the latest version of netplan, I think your answer just needs one little tweek to work. PEAP works with a server cert but does not use a client cert and auths the clients with passwords so your config would not work with PEAP as far as I can tell. If you change the method from PEAP to TLS, then it will auth with client certs and I think it would probably work with latest netplan. That said, I am still very thankful for you getting me going the right direction on solving this.

Comment: @CullenFluffyJennings give the script a try, and tweak it if required, and let us know how you do.

Comment: @PhillipRemaker did my answer help solve your problem? Did you have to make any mods to it?

Comment: Using your pointers, @CullenFluffyJennings uncovered a bug in NetPlan. I am satisfied that your (@heynnema 's) answer is authoritative, though you may want to edit it when Cullen reports the final disposition and bugfix. Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: @PhillipRemaker yes, please ask Cullen to update me.

Comment: @CullenFluffyJennings what was the final take on this?

Comment: @heynnema - When I dug into your script, the problem is that netplan does not have any way to use to use the Wired driver which is needed for the wired 802.1x. I've written a patch to netplan at https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/pull/80 - this adds a "wired: true" option which could allow that script work.

Comment: In all of this, I think your script is about right but netplan just did not really support this.

Answer (score 1):

The default netplan that ship with Ubuntu 18.04.02 does not support wired authentication so there is not chance of if working. The latest version on github in early March 2019 does support authentication but it is lacking other things that are required. The WPA supplicant requires a CLI flag to use the wired driver for it to work with and I wrote a PR to add this to netplan. Netplan also handle hashed passwords in a way that breaks them so there is another PR to fix that.

If you want to try these, PR, the instructions are:

1. Have a server install of Ubuntu 18.04.02
2. Install supplicant

   - sudo apt install wpasupplicant"
3. Install needed build tools with

   - sudo apt install make cpp pkg-config  libyaml-dev  uuid-dev  libgio2.0-cil-dev  libglib2.0-dev  pandoc
4. Get the patched netplan software with

   - git clone https://github.com/fluffy/netplan.git
   - cd netplan
   - git checkout all
5. Build and install it with

   - make
   - sudo make install
6. Generate a hashed version of your password

   - echo -n 'MyPassword' | iconv -t UTF-16LE | openssl md4 -binary | xxd -p
   - history -c
7. Edit the netplan config file

   - cd /etc/netplan
   - sudo mv  50-cloud-init.yaml config.yaml
   - sudo emacs  /etc/netplan/config.yaml
8. Get it to look something like:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp0s31f6:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
            auth:
                key-management: 802.1x
                wired: true
                method: ttls
                identity: fluffy@cisco.com
                password: hash:83...11
```

9. Apply it with

   - sudo netplan apply
10. At this point if you reboot, it should work but some things to check to help debug
11. Check the WPA supplicant config file

    - sudo cat /run/netplan/wpa-enp0s31f6.conf

and it should look like

```
 ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
 network={
   key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
   eap=TTLS
  identity="fluffy@cisco.com"
  password=hash:83..11
}
```

Make sure there are not quotes around the password if using hashed passwords.

12. Check the systemd template

    - ls /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan*enp0s31f6.service

It should return something like

/run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa-wired@enp4s0.service

The key thing is to check that it as wpa-wired in it

13. Test the auth works with passwords and all

    - kill any running version of wpa_supplicant then do
    - sudo wpa_supplicant -c /run/netplan/wpa-enp0s31f6.conf -i enp0s31f6 -D wired

You will see a flow of info about the 802.1x messages and near the end there should be a "Authentication succeeded"

You will need to Ctrl^C this kill it.

14. Reboot and enjoy ....

Comment: That's kind of insane. Please update the answer with the right version when the Netplan team rolls in the patch. Also, remind me what year this is that such a fundamental fumble could happen.

Comment: I've updated `netplan.io` to the latest version (`netplan.io/bionic-updates 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.4 amd64`) and it works now for me.