# Install Ubuntu Server where WiFi/Network authentication is required

Tags: wireless, system-installation

I need to install Ubuntu Server (19.04) for a development on a network which is requiring authentication.
As Ubuntu Server installation disk doesn't come with Lynx, I cannot download anything, and considering that I tried to use Curl but they have some javascript to be executed, the task is very tedius.
Is there an alternative solution for that?

Comment: Have you set up the wireless details in netplan? Please see the example in: /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 actually it is a wired connection, but it is using the same authentication method as the WiFi, hence my question.

Comment: Is it using TLS or PEAP or similar? Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124164/how-do-you-configure-netplan-on-ubuntu-to-store-802-1x-credentials-securely

Comment: Can you share a wired connection by using a separate laptop connected wirelessly?

Comment: @chili555 It is not a problem of TLS, it is just that there is an intermediate page that I have to pass through. I mean, a captative portal.

Comment: @PSA Unfortunatelly I can't.