# How to use hashed passwords with netplan (for wpa2 enterprise) instead of plain text passwords?

Tags: password, netplan, hash

I have a question concerning this post [How do you configure Netplan on Ubuntu to store 802.1x credentials securely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124164/how-do-you-configure-netplan-on-ubuntu-to-store-802-1x-credentials-securely)

Because I am a nooby, I don't have the reputation to comment on posts and creating a new question is what the moderators suggested me.

I used the format `password: hash:83...11` in my config file for netplan, but the file `/run/netplan/wpa-enp0s31f6.conf` still has quotes around the hash (it shouldn't).

(When I use the clear text password everything works fine!)

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers
Jago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1819831 for which a fix is in progress.

Note that while the linked question speaks of storing credentials "securely", the hash that is stored in the config is plaintext-equivalent.  If someone has this hash, they have everything they need to access this network.  So hashing should be considered a mechanism only of hiding the actual text of the password, and not a mechanism for protecting your network connection.