# How to connect raspberry pi to WIFI that requires username and password?

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi, netplan

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to a wifi that requires an account to login i.e username and password. I have successfully connected the pi to an open wifi that only requires SSID and password but I cannot find the option to add username.

I used the netplan 50-cloud-init.yaml file as bellow with my SSID and password.

What do i need to add to put in my username.

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "MY_HIDEN_SID":
                    password: "MY_PASSWORD"
            dhcp4: true
```

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu?

Comment: The raspberrypi runs ubuntu

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124164/how-do-you-configure-netplan-on-ubuntu-to-store-802-1x-credentials-securely

Answer (score 0):

If the wifi requires a username and password in order to connect to the AP, then you are not using wpa-psk (the default authentication, password-only) but you are probably instead using wpa-eap.  For this, you need a configuration that looks like:

```
wifis:
    wlan0:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "MY_HIDDEN_SID":
                auth:
                  key-management: eap
                  identity: MY_USERNAME
                  password: "MY_PASSWORD"
        dhcp4: true
```

More information can be found at https://netplan.io/examples/#connecting-to-wpa-enterprise-wireless-networks.

If your network is configured such that you can associate with the AP without a username, but you have to enter a login and password on a *portal* in order to connect to the Internet, then that is not something that netplan supports managing.  To non-interactively interact with a wireless portal, you would need to do scripting around a tool such as wget or curl that you would launch after the network interface comes up.